# Read files And Modify filename from the azure storage containers in Azure Databricks

Tags: scala, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks, apache-spark-xml

I am ingesting Large XML file and generating individual JSON according to the XML Element, I am using SPARK-XML in azure databricks.
Code to create the json file as

```
commercialInfo
.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.json("/mnt/processed/" + "commercialInfo")
```

I am able to extract the XML element node and writing into the Azure storage container.
A folder is created in the container and inside the folder we have name with the guid not with the filename.

[image]

Can anyone suggest if we have control over the File Name created in the container, i.e part-0000 into something meaningful name so that it can be read using some Azure Blob trigger.

Comment: see if that works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/75579796/680074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to control the file name using standard spark library, but you can use Hadoop API for managing file system - save output in temporary directory and then move file to the requested path.

> Spark uses Hadoop File Format, which requires data to be partitioned - that's why you have `part-0000` files.

In order to change filename, try to add something like this in your code:

In Scala it will look like:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val file = fs.globStatus(new Path("path/file.csv/part*"))(0).getPath().getName()

fs.rename(new Path("csvDirectory/" + file), new Path("mydata.csv"))
fs.delete(new Path("mydata.csv-temp"), true)
```

OR

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.rename(new Path("csvDirectory/data.csv/part-0000"), new Path("csvDirectory/newData.csv"))
```